# Can't create table in mariadb and this table does not exist

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I Want to create table family Using this command :

```
CREATE TABLE `FAMILY` ( `FAMILY_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL, `PERSON_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, `CREATED_BY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, `LAST_UPDATED_BY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, `LAST_UPDATED_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `STATUS` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`FAMILY_ID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I got the result :
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`bfm`.`FAMILY`' already exists
After That I run desc command :

> desc FAMILY;

I got result :
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'bfm.FAMILY' doesn't exist

I use show tables command and got family table doesn't exist.

But I am not able to create family table .

I have created a bug to mariadb for this issue. You
 can visit it here :

[ERROR 1050 Table already exists](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9875)

Comment: Are you looking at the right database?  Maybe you are looking at a DB which does not have this table, but another DB does already have it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  am working on one database.there is no two database dear.

Comment: Try: use bfm; SHOW TABLES;

Comment: @BerndBuffen I have already use this .There is no "FAMILY" table

Comment: take a look in the DATADIR/bfm . there can an old file with the NAME FAMILY.ibd or .frm that not a correct Table but they cant create a new one. You are try the test as root ?